# How to merge two pandas dataframe using an OR condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe and I'd like to join based on a couple of columns. However, my join logic has an 'OR' in it, e.g. I want to join based on columns ['A','B','C'] OR ['A','B','D']. I have the following code to join based on one set of columns but how I can add the second set of columns?

```
 pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner',left_on = ['A','B','C'], right_on = ['A','B','C'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, since `left_on` and `right_on` are the same just use `on`:

```
d_1 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner', on = ['A','B','C'])
d_2 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner', on = ['A','B','D'])
d_3 = pd.concat([d_1,d_2]).drop_duplicates()
```